# Redirect to domain always with WWW attached causes error with subdomains

Tags: .htaccess

I have the code below in my website's `.htaccess` file:

```
#redirect non www to http://wwww
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works fine but when I decide to access the forum on my site as a subdomain, the `.htaccess` is screwing everything.

So normally the url to forum is:

```
http://www.eetutorials.com/forum
```

but since I linked the `forum` folder as a subdomain, it does not work anymore and redirects to:

```
http://www.forum.eetutorials.com/forum/
```

which obviously is wrong! any idea how can I fix that by adding some conditions into `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change a condition:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.`

to this one:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^eetutorials.com$`